# Outcome of double-recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have a question regarding these lines of code. I was trying to figure out what the print statement would show:

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]
print f("abcd")
```

I was expecting it to print: `dcba` but instead it showed: `dbca`.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me why exactly this is happening. My goal is not to change to code in a way that it prints `dcba` but just to understand why it is behaving like it is. Thanks in advance for every help provided.
Cheers

Comment: Looks like a rather meaningless transformation. Where did you get this code?

Comment: Your expectation matches `return f(s[1:]) + s[0]` not `return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]`.

Comment: Write out each of the function calls and their results. `f(f(s[1:]))` first computes `f(s[1:])`. The result is strange because the double call to `f` does a sort of shuffle on the list before calling `f` again.

Comment: I know that it is rather meaningless. I'm currently learning how to code and I use Python as a tool for doing so. I got this code as a "trick" question, and I still wonder why it behaves the way it does. So as I said, my goal is not to fix the code, but to exactly understand its current behavior! I'm not trying to solve a specific problem using this recursive function but rather using this function to get a better understanding of induction/recursion, which I (obviously, see above) don't really have yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the bottom up.

Calling `f` on a one-character string just returns that string. Ex. f("a") returns "a".

Calling `f` on a two-character string returns that string reversed. Ex. f("ab") == f(f("b")) + "a" == f("b") + "a" == "b" + "a" == "ba".

Calling `f` on a three character string returns that string with the leftmost character moved to the right end. Ex. f("abc") == f(f("bc")) + "a" == f("cb") + "a" == "bc" + "a" == "bca".

Calling `f` on a four character string returns something convoluted which corresponds to the result you got: f("abcd") == f(f("bcd")) + "a" == f("cdb") + "a" == "dbc" + "a" == "dbca".

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thwarted by the minimum edit size restriction once again... the second to last term on the second to last paragraph should be `"bc" + "a"`, not `f("bc") + "a"`.

Comment: So it should rather be f("cb") + "a" ==  "bc" + "a" right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow the calls add some print statements:

```
>>> def f(s):
...     print
...     print "recieved", s
...     if len(s) <= 1:
...         print "returning", s
...         return s
...     print "returning f(f(%s)) + %s" % (s[1:], s[0])
...     return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]
...
>>> print f("abcd")

recieved abcd
returning f(f(bcd)) + a

recieved bcd
returning f(f(cd)) + b

recieved cd
returning f(f(d)) + c

recieved d
returning d

recieved d
returning d

recieved dc
returning f(f(c)) + d

recieved c
returning c

recieved c
returning c

recieved cdb
returning f(f(db)) + c

recieved db
returning f(f(b)) + d

recieved b
returning b

recieved b
returning b

recieved bd
returning f(f(d)) + b

recieved d
returning d

recieved d
returning d
dbca
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ran your code through a debugger so I can't exactly see the *stack trace*, but it is due to you recursively calling `f()` twice. This seems over-manipulate the string leading to an unintended transformation. If you want to reverse a string recursively, the code below is fairly popular:

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return s
    return f(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

**Sample Outcome:**

```
print f("abcd")
>>> dcba
```

That being said (*I assume this is a learning exercise?*), a far more **pythonic** way to reverse a string is to use an [extended slice syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) `[being:end:step]`.

```
print 'abcd'[::-1]
>>> dcba
```